# Fitting nls to grouped data R

Tags: r, nls

I'm trying to fit a non-linear model to a series of measurements collected on several plots throughout the season. Below is a subsample from the larger dataset. 
data:

> dput(nee.example)
>   structure(list(julian = c(159L, 159L, 159L, 159L, 159L, 159L, 
>   159L, 159L, 159L, 159L, 159L, 159L, 159L, 159L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 
>   169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 
>   169L), blk = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("e", "w"), class = "factor"), type = structure(c(1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("b", 
>   "g"), class = "factor"), plot = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), trt = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "a", class = "factor"), 
>       cloth = c(25L, 50L, 75L, 100L, 0L, 25L, 50L, 75L, 100L, 0L, 
>       25L, 50L, 75L, 100L, 0L, 25L, 50L, 100L, 0L, 25L, 50L, 75L, 
>       100L, 0L, 25L, 50L, 75L, 75L, 100L), plotID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
>       13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L
>       ), flux = c(0.76, 0.6, 0.67, 0.7, 1.72, 1.63, -7.8, 0.89, 
>       0.51, 0.76, 0.48, 0.62, 0.18, 0.21, 3.87, 2.44, 1.26, -1.39, 
>       2.18, 1.9, 0.81, -0.04, -0.83, 1.99, 1.55, 0.57, -0.02, -0.16, 
>       -2.12), ChT = c(18.6, 19.1, 19.6, 19.1, 16.5, 17.3, 18.3, 
>       19, 18.6, 17.2, 18.4, 19, 19.2, 20.6, 22, 21.9, 22.4, 23.8, 
>       20.7, 21.5, 22.5, 23.3, 23.8, 20.1, 20.8, 21.2, 21.8, 21.8, 
>       21.4), par = c(129.9, 210.2, 305.4, 796.6, 1.3, 62.7, 149.9, 
>       171.2, 453.3, 1.3, 129.7, 409.3, 610, 1148.6, 1.3, 115.2, 
>       237, 814.6, 1.3, 105.4, 293.4, 472.1, 955.9, 1.3, 100.5, 
>       290, 467, 413.6, 934.2)), .Names = c("julian", "blk", "type", 
>   "plot", "trt", "cloth", "plotID", "flux", "ChT", "par"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
>   -29L))

I need to fit the following model (rec.hyp, below) to each plot on each date and retrieve the parameter estimates for each julian-plotID combination. After some poking around, it sounded like nlsList would be an ideal function because of the grouping aspect:

```
library(nlme)
rec.hyp <- nlsList(flux ~ Re - ((Amax*par)/(k+par)) | julian/plotID,
             data=nee.example,
             start=c(Re=3, k=300, Amax=5),
             na.action=na.omit)
coef(rec.hyp)
```

However I keep getting the same error message:

```
Error in nls(formula = formula, data = data, start = start, control = control) : 
step factor 0.000488281 reduced below 'minFactor' of 0.000976562
```

I've tried tweaking the controls in nls.control to increase the maxIter and tol, but the same error message is displayed. And I've altered the initial starting values to no avail.

It should be noted that I need to fit the model using least squares in order to be consistent with prior work.

Questions:

1. Is my grouping structure allowed in nlsList. In other words, can I nest plotID within julian? Could this be the source of my error.
2. I've read that inappropriate starting parameter estimates cause the error message, yet I get the same message after changing them.

I feel like I'm missing something simple here, but my brain is fried.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Answer to Q1**: your grouping structure is correct. You can validate it by running `nls` on a subset of your data:

```
rec.hyp.test <- nls(flux ~ Re - ((Amax*par)/(k+par)),
                   data=subset(nee.example,julian==159 & plotID==3),
                   start=c(Re=3, k=300, Amax=5),
                   na.action=na.omit)
coef(rec.hyp.test)
#        Re           k        Amax 
# 0.7208943 792.4412287   0.8972519 

coef(rec.hyp)[3,]
#              Re        k      Amax
# 159/3 0.7208943 792.4412 0.8972519
```

**Answer to Q2**: Some data sets just cannot be properly fitted by a given model. From the `flux ~ Re - ((Amax*par)/(k+par))` formula, one might expect that `flux` monotonically decreases with `par` (or increases, if Amax < 0). Just for curiosity, I plotted one of the data sets that cause `nls` to fail:

```
plot(flux~par,subset(nee.example,julian==159 & plotID==1))
```

and found that it was not monotonic, and I'd even say that it had no any trend at all! I guess that even if you force `nls` to get some solution for this case, it could be well possible a spurious one, so you might just want to leave it unfitted (viz. NA).

[image]

I would also suggest to perform a visual inspection of the input data and fitting model quality. With `R` and packages like `reshape2` and `ggplot2`, you can easily plot hundreds of them, and even taking a quick look at them will help you to stay out of trouble.

Comment: thanks for your response, very helpful.  Is it possible to force `nls` to complete the model fitting of other groups even when there are errors in others (e.g, the one you graphed above)?  It would be nice to have the model fit the "good" relationships then return to the "bad" ones for quality control.  Otherwise, I'll follow your suggestion of `reshape` or `ggplot2` to identify outliers then rerun the `nlsList` model.

Comment: 1. Look at the `coef(rec.hyp)` output--`nlsList` automatically completes the analysis and returns `NA` for the groups that caused errors. 2. I think that a visual inspection would be a good idea whether your data are 'good' or 'bad' in terms of fitting. 3. I would also suggest to look at the `shiny` package, which can be used for building a nice and shiny GUI for your quality control program